# How can I plot a Kernel Density Estimation in a projected coordinate system in Python?

Tags: coordinate-system, numpy, matplotlib, kernel-density

I am trying to plot a Kernel Density Estimation calculated from a geopandas GeoDataFrame in UTM. I am using sci-kit learn's `KernelDensity`, because other implementations don't allow for much flexibility in terms of kernel choice. The original point data is in lat/lon.

The output now is a masked numpy array in lat/lon, but I am a bit lost as to how to project this into UTM coordinates.

Another (probably sub-optimal) alternative I thought of was to project the GeoDataFrame and then calculate the KDE. This outputs an empty array, though.

Here's a minimal working example where the data is projected to UTM before the KD is estimated:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import contextily as cx
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from sklearn import neighbors

def kde2D(A, bandwidth, xbins=100j, ybins=100j, weights=None, **kwargs): # https://stackoverflow.com/a/41639690/10955832
    """Build 2D kernel density estimate (KDE)."""
    
    x,y = (A.flatten()[a::2] for a in [0,1])
    # create grid of sample locations (default: 100x100)
    xx, yy = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():xbins, 
                      y.min():y.max():ybins]

    xy_sample = np.vstack([yy.ravel(), xx.ravel()]).T
    xy_train  = np.vstack([y, x]).T

    kde_skl = neighbors.KernelDensity(bandwidth=bandwidth, **kwargs)

    kde_skl.fit(xy_train, sample_weight=weights)

    # score_samples() returns the log-likelihood of the samples
    z = np.exp(kde_skl.score_samples(xy_sample))
    return xx, yy, np.reshape(z, xx.shape)

queens = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("nybb")).to_crs("EPSG:4326").iloc[1:2]#.geometry.bounds

bounds = [x for x in queens.bounds.values[0]]
r_x = np.random.uniform(bounds[0], bounds[2], size=(500)) # generate some random points
r_y = np.random.uniform(bounds[1], bounds[3], size=(500))

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame([Point(x,y) for x,y in zip(r_x, r_y)], geometry=0).set_crs("EPSG:4326")

df_utm = df.loc[~df.geometry.isna()].to_crs('EPSG:32618') # reproject to UTM
X = np.array([list(x.coords[0]) for x in df_utm.geometry])

xx, yy, zz = kde2D(X, 0.05, kernel="linear", weights=None)
zz_m = np.log(np.ma.masked_where(zz < 1, zz))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize= (10,10))

ax.pcolormesh(xx, yy, zz_m, cmap=plt.cm.OrRd, alpha=0.7)
cx.add_basemap(ax, crs='EPSG:32618', source=cx.providers.CartoDB.PositronNoLabels)
```

This currently outputs only the basemap at the right location, because the xx and yy arrays are not empty, while the zz array is empty.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am facing exactly the same issue